# Find value; if found, move to the next row and delete all empty rows until next non-empty row found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet like so:

Column A

```
Blank
Blank
Something
Fax Number:
Blank
Blank 
Blank
Next non empty row
```

I am using the following VBA code to find my value 'Fax Number:' in column A:

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("A:A")
Rng.Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="Fax Number:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    'do it something
Else
    Dim MyRange As Object
    Set MyRange = cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row
    MyRange.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

If found, all the empty rows below fax number should be deleted until the next non empty row.

Giving this result:

```
Column A
Blank
Blank
Something
Fax Number:
Next non empty row
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong? I get an object not defined error on: 
`Set MyRange = cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row`.

Comment: Why `.Select` when you could do `Range("A:A").Find`? Leave `Selection` to the macro recorder. Also... `cell` doesn't seem to be declared, do you have `Option Explicit` specified? ..and if you have nothing to do when `cell Is Nothing`, then why not do `If Not cell Is Nothing` instead, and remove that useless empty block of code?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to clarify *where* you're getting that error, and when (compile-time? run-time?) - what's the *exact* error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, without useing `Select` and `Selection`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseFind()

Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

Set Rng = Range("A:A")

Set C = Rng.Find(What:="Fax Number:", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If C Is Nothing Then
    'do it something
Else
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MyRange As Range
    LastRow = C.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - 1 '<-- get last row of Blank
    Set MyRange = Range(C.Offset(1, 0), Cells(LastRow, C.Column)) '<-- set the deleted range
    MyRange.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This gives a Type Mismatch error on the `Set C = Rng.Find` line

Comment: @TylerH  did u copy my entire code ? Also the variable declaration?

Comment: I copied your whole code and stepped through it on a spreadsheet with the values in Column A copied from OP's post.

Comment: Odd; running it a second time works fine. Must have been because Rng was set already and there was a value outside of the previous Rng. Additionally, hopefully this code will only run one time; if you run it a second time, it will delete the "next non empty row" contents because it's stored that as a previously blank cell to delete.

Comment: @TylerH there can be multiple scenarios where this code might break, I am not writing the entire application for the PO, just fixing the issue raised, no?

Comment: Right, but the concern was that the code should not be run more than once or you will erase data that you can't recover via Undo. That's worth a caveat, IMO.